# Synchronize Apache Flink streams based on a time stamp

Tags: apache-flink

I have several use cases where I need to synchronize multiple streams based on a time stamp.

Here is an example where I want to sync trade bars and quote bars which I generate for example like this from raw trades and quotes, which I aggregate:

```
val tradeBars: DataStream[TradeBar] = trades
  .assignAscendingTimestamps(_.epochMillis)
  .keyBy("key")
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5)))
  .process(new TimeTradeBar(new DownTick()))

val quotesWithFlow = quotes
  .assignAscendingTimestamps(_.epochMillis)
  .keyBy("key")
  .countWindow(2, 1)
  .reduce((previousQuote, quote) => Quote.localOrderFlow(previousQuote, quote))
  .assignAscendingTimestamps(_.epochMillis)
  .keyBy("key")

val quoteBars: DataStream[QuoteBar] = quotesWithFlow
  .assignAscendingTimestamps(_.epochMillis)
  .keyBy("key")
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5)))
  .process(new QuoteBars.TimeQuoteBar())

val joined: JoinedStreams[TradeBar, QuoteBar]#Where[LocalDateTime]#EqualTo = tradeBars
  .join(quoteBars)
  .where(_.start).equalTo(_.start)
  // need a window here, just want to sync on same time window
```

I tried to use the window join function of Flink, but apparently this expects now a window function and then I can do an apply method. All I want is to sync the streams on the same time window. I suspect that was not the intention of the join method.

I have a working implementation which uses the Flink stream connect method. I applied it to the trade bars stream and the raw quote stream, but that requires that I code a pretty messy CoProcessFunction myself

```
CoProcessTradeBarsAndQuotes() extends CoProcessFunction[TradeBar, Quote, (TradeBar, QuoteBar)]
{}
```

Which is pretty messy because I have to keep track of quotes in a buffer and carefully perform the aggregation from the process1 and process2 function. I guess there must be a simpler way, I just don't see it. Grateful for any help and ideas.

Comment: Can you clarify your use of the phrase "sync the streams" here if the window join isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: Consider this use case: You have multiple streams for which you do time based window aggregation on exactly the same windows, say 1 hour windows, which results in a set of data for each hour per day. Now you have multiple of these streams and you want to joint them so that you can output the union of the data, per window and send it downstream. Concrete example: assume 2 stocks. You create open, high, low, close price for each hour window, giving you 4 values for each. Now you want to join it so that you get the 8 values as a vector.

Comment: If I understood it correctly what you really want is to assign events to a proper window based on its timestamp? You do not do any join, but you rather `union` those two streams. The whole concept of watermark will ensure that both(multiple) streams will be aligned regarding to its timestamp. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Dawid. However, this does not work, because union can only handle the same data type, which is usually not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the logic you'd use to decide which two stocks (of likely many) to join, but in general I'd solve this by generating an output record from the first window function (open, high, low, close, stock) with an additional field representing the time (truncated to the hour) of the window, then key by that time field and do another windowing operation to create the join of the stocks that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The stocks are an arbitrary choice, like a portfolio that you like to build. Usually a small number 3, to 10, sometimes 50. I thought about to use keyed streams too. But is that not likely to be inefficient? The keyBy also has some implications how the calculations are done across a cluster. But as I key first relative to the stock symbol, it may be distributed anyway, so key by time window now may now have to bring the data to a single node, which has to happen anyway. How about now to get all the windows over time? That is not apparent to me.